# can we use css tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

first of all what is $('#gallery').gallerrax do?

is it anything to do with css. Else how can we use css tags in jquery?

Comment: I would recommend you look at the jQuery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `gallerrax` is a custom jQuery plugin, and I believe that only the author of it can tell you what it does. In that peace of code you are calling `gallerrax` for all HTML elements that have ID attribute equal to `gallery`.

There is no CSS tags, because CSS is not a HTML element. You can deal with CSS using jQuery like [>this<](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/).

Good luck. =)

Answer (score 0):

this is [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

 I recommend to you [jQuery Docs to start](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)
You can come back with more specific question...